# Parse cURL to get information PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have a cURL response:

```
<html version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 2.0//EN" xml:lang="en" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml2.xsd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Request Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV id="content">
<P class="heading1"><B>Error Status Code:</B> 'BadRequest'</P>
<P><B>Details: </B>Customer email address is not unique - xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com</P>
</DIV>
</BODY>
</html>
```

And when I convert it to an XML Object via SimpleXMLElement I cannot access the content inside the P tags. Is there a quick way to either get the header response (400) or even better the information sent by the cURL system.

I am getting back the result:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, SPEKTRIX_CERT);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, SPEKTRIX_KEY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'handleHeader');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'handleHeader');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w'));
$requestHeaders = array();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $requestHeaders);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Thanks for any insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
...prepare $ch...
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo $info['http_code']; // will output 400 for an invalid request
```

Comment: Thanks. That does give me the 400 response but is there any way of getting the info '...Customer email ....' without having to parse through the content?